# Upper bound on $\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k - c)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, upper-lower-bounds

I know that $\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{1}{n-1} = O(\frac{1}{n})$. I confronted a similar situation but now I have some finite constant $c \in \mathbb{R}$ in the denominator:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k - c)}.
\end{equation}

Can we upper bound this in terms of $n$ (and $c$ if needed) (using Big-O notation is completely fine)?

One thing I've tried is first expressing $\frac{1}{k(k-c)} = \frac{1}{c}(\frac{1}{k-c} - \frac{1}{k})$, so that our equation becomes

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{c}\sum_{k=n}^\infty (\frac{1}{k-c} - \frac{1}{k}).
\end{equation} From here, I am stuck. I think some cancellations might help us, or maybe thinking about the absolute value ($\lvert \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k - c)} \rvert$), but I'm not sure. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you split the sum based on $k\pmod {c}$, you will find that it telescopes.

Comment: @JoshuaWang $c$ is not supposed to be an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple, explicit bound. For $n > \max\{0, c\}$, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k - c)}
&= \frac{1}{c} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k-c} - \frac{1}{k}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{c} \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} x^{k-1}(x^{-c} - 1) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{c} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1}\frac{x^{-c} - 1}{1-x} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Now for $0 < x < 1$, we have

\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{-c} - 1}{c}
&= \int_{x}^{1} t^{-c-1} \, \mathrm{d}t
\leq \begin{cases}
x^{-c-1}(1-x), & c > -1, \\
1-x, & c \leq -1.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Plugging this back to the last integral, for $n > \max\{0, c+1\}$ we obtain

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k - c)}
\leq \frac{1}{n-\max\{0, c+1\}}
\end{align*}

Or, if you are willing to include the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) into your vocabulary of closed-form expressions, we can compute the sum as

$$ \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k - c)} = \frac{\psi(n) - \psi(n-c)}{c} $$

and utilize asymptotic expansion of $\psi(\cdot)$ for further use.

Comment: Great answer! If $c \geq 0$, then the upper bound becomes $\lvert \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k - c)} \rvert \leq \big\lvert \frac{1}{n - c - 1}\big\rvert$. Is this true for any $n < \max\{0, c+1\}$?